# How to change "Private Style Definitions for <myNotebook>.nb" in a saved private stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet, customization

Now that I found our how to save the private stylesheet opened by "Format->Edit Stylesheet...", by using "File->Save" from that window, I would like to know how to change the "heading" that still says "Private Style Definitions for someNotebook.nb".  This is displayed above the "Choose a style" drop-down box button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand.  You don't want it to say "Private Style Definitions" *at all* but instead "someNotebook.nb style definitions" -- is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the stylesheet Notebook you need to change the Option:

```
StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
```

to read:

```
StyleDefinitions->"StylesheetFormatting.nb"
```

Applying this is complicated by the default stylesheet settings that disable evaluation.
Here is Palette generating code to create a [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) to apply it:

```
CreatePalette@
 Button["Set StylesheetFormatting", 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "StylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Evaluating that code should create a palette that looks like this:

[image]

Open and focus the private style sheet, then click that button and it should immediately apply the change.

Otherwise use a text editor on the Notebook and replace `PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb` with `StylesheetFormatting.nb`.

Comment: I guess EMacs will also work. ;)

Comment: @StevenHatton Directly editing the file is fine too but I am hesitant to recommend it as it is more likely to corrupt a Notebook than the built in tools.  Thanks for the Accept.

Comment: FWIW, when I try the first approach, nothing happens.  (In fact, nothing happens if I try to evaluate `2 + 2` in a notebook created with **Format > Edit Stylesheet...**; evaluation seems to be disabled altogether in such notebooks, judging by all the options that are disabled under the **Evaluation** menu).  When I try the second approach, I can find the setting as you described, but I am not able to modify it; i.e. the interface treats this item as "read only".  I'm using version 10.4.

Comment: @kjo Thank you!  It seems something has changed.  *Old* private style sheets like the one I checked this in allow me to evaluate new cells, but one I created just now to test this did not.

Comment: After I wrote my comment, I found that these notebook's have their Evaluatable attribute set to False; so toggling that restores the functionality you described.

Comment: As I mentioned, I was not able to use the Options Inspector approach either.  (The option was not editable.)  Does the Options Inspector method work for you in a version > 7?

Comment: @kjo I revised my answer to use a palette to apply this setting.  Please test it.

Comment: Clever idea!  It worked really well for me.  Thanks!